# Why do you skip void function calls without catching them?

Tags: c, return, function-call

I want to call a function that calculates the width of a circle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void area(double*);
int main()
{
    void* vp = NULL;
    double r;
    printf("input value : ");
    scanf(" %lf", &r);
    (double*)vp = &r;
    void area(vp);
}
void area(double* dp)
{
    double result;
    result = (*dp) * (*dp) * (3.14);
    printf("circle are is : %.2lf", result);
    return 1;
}*
```

---

I want to call a function in the //void area (vp)//, but I can not catch the error in visual stdio and proceed as it is. Do you know what the cause is?

Comment: The cast in the assignment `vp = &r` is not needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The "visual-studio-2015" tag probably means expecting C behavior standardized something like two decades ago is too much to ask for here....

Comment: Hmmm. `area()` has return type `void`, yet returns an `int`.

Comment: You can't return a value if your function declares it will return a void.

Comment: Basically, most of this isn't valid C. You need a good C programming book and a better compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *call* the function, you write `area(vp);` **not** `void area(vp);`.

The latter, as it appears in the function `main`, is a *function prototype* and has no run-time effect.

And fix that definition of PI: yours is terribly inadequate given that you use a `double` type. See [Math constant PI value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912151/math-constant-pi-value-in-c)

Comment: Is it a function declaration?  In some ways, it is closest to that, but `vp` is not a type name so I think it is just a hybrid mess.  The `void` prevents it from being a function call; the `vp` prevents it from being a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
  area(&r);
```

instead of the wrong and superfluous

```
 void area(vp);
```

Adding to the obvious mistake you made in the syntax

- I don't see any reason for `vp` to be there.
- to ensure success for `scanf()`, always check for the return value of the call.
- Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.6.4,

  > A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
  >   is `void`.  [....]

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with the code.

For starters it is unclear why the pointer `vp` is declared as having the type void * though in the program it is used only to point objects of the type double.

Why not to declare it like

```
double *vp = NULL;
```

As result this trick with the pointer

```
(double*)vp = &r;
```

will not compile because in the left side the expression `(double*)vp` is `rvalue` and may not be assigned.

You could just write

```
vp = &r;
```

The second problem is that this statement

```
void area(vp);
```

is also invalid. To call the function you should write

```
area(vp);
```

And the third problem is that a function that has the return type void shall not specify an expression in the return statement

This statement shall be removed.

```
return 1;
```

From the C Standard (6.8.6.4 The return statement)

> 1 **A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a
>   function whose return type is void.** A return statement without an
>   expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

There is no sense to declare the parameter of the function as having a referenced type.

The function definition could look like

```
double area( double dp )
{
    const double PI = 3.14;

    return dp * dp * PI;
}
```

The statement with the call pf printf should be moved in main

```
printf( "circle are is : %.2lf", area( r ) );
```