# Should missing definition of object / function with non-reserved identifier lead to diagnostics?

Tags: c, linker, language-lawyer, linker-errors, libc

Sample code:

```
void accept(int x);

int main(void)
{
        accept(0);
        return 0;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>

$ clang t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>

$ cl t719.c /std:c11 /Za
t719.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol accept referenced in function main

$ icc t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
```

Consider that the user forgot to define `accept`. We see that no diagnostics may be produced. Is diagnostics required?

UPD: Another example:

```
extern int y0;

int main(void)
{
        return y0;
}

# linux (begin)
$ gcc t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
undefined reference to `y0'

$ clang t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
undefined reference to `y0'

$ icc t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
# program returned: 243
# linux (end)

# windows (begin)
# gcc in cygwin
$ gcc t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
# program returned: 255

# clang in cygwin
$ clang t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
# program returned: 255

$ cl t719.c /std:c11 /Za
unresolved external symbol _y0 referenced in function _main

$ LLVM/12.0.0/bin/clang t719.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
# program returned: 72

$ icl -Qstd=c11 t719.c 
<nothing>
# program returned: 65
# windows (end)
```

Comment: Nope — diagnostics are not required when the symbol is satisfied by the standard libraries linked by the compiler.  WIth GCC and Clang (on Unix-like systems) `accept()` is a function that accesses a system call.  The standard library provides it, so there's no need for a diagnostic.  Was `cl` running on Unix or Windows?  Is `cl` the Microsoft C compiler or something else?

Comment: change 'accept' to 'froodle' and see what happens, accept is the name of a unix/linux system call

Comment: Umm, [`accept()` doggone well **is** reserved on a lot of systems](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/accept.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The fact that system-provided libraries provide a function does not mean the identifier is reserved, particularly if no related headers are included.

Comment: @EricPostpischil [Here it does](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html): "All functions and external identifiers defined in XBD Headers are reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."  `accept()` is a reserved identifier on POSIX systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, `cl` is the Microsoft C compiler. It was running on Windows. Question: what `y0` is used for (see UPD)?

Comment: `y0` is one of the Bessel functions in the maths library.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Well, they tried. [1.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap01.html#tag_14_01) indicates “alignment” to the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) and says “any conflict… is unintentional.” Consider that a strictly conforming program may use `accept` for its own purposes, and a conforming implementation must accept and faithfully execute strictly conforming programs. So POSIX cannot reserve additional identifiers, other than those reserved for implementations, while conforming to the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since the C standard does not have `accept`, the user expects that there are zero external definitions for the identifier `accept`. Hence, the user expects a diagnostics. Does it mean that the `-std=c11` is violated?

Comment: @pmor: The C standard does not require a diagnostic for this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK. Why "there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier" is in Semantics, rather than in Constraints?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Meaning that an implementation is free to silently fail to resolve all external object and function references (phase 8).

Comment: @pmor: No, it is not free to resolve references. It is free not to diagnose missing definitions or multiple definitions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not to forget that "If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined". If "multiple definitions" is OK (some policy may be used to select the definition), then what about "missing definitions"? How an implementation can behave after _not_ diagnosing missing definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 §6.9 ¶5 says:

> … If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier;…

Since a “shall” is violated, but it is not in a constraint paragraph, C 2018 §4 ¶2 makes this undefined behavior:

> If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined…

The clause on diagnostics, §5.1.1.3, does not require a diagnostic for this:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.